# EasyPG always asks to pick a gpg key even though epa-file-encrypt-to is set

Tags: gpg, emacs, org-mode

I want emacs to use one specific key for encryption files. So, when I make a `*.org.gpg` file and save it, `easypg` should automatically transparently take the key and encrypt a buffer.

Instead, it asks me to pick a key that would be used. Every time I save a new file.

But if close a buffer and open it again the system starts to work properly. I've put the value for the `epa-file-encrypt-to` variable

- [this is how it looks](https://paste.debian.net/1267258/) for newly created buffer, and
- [this is how it looks](https://paste.debian.net/1267259/) for closed/opened buffer

You see,it's the same. But behavior is different. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got it. According to https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/epa-file.el#n307

the variable epa-file-encrypt-to should be a file local variable. So, global one doesn't work. And if I set local variable via template as the

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("$myKey") -*-
```

line it behaves as:

1. I make a file the line is created but not readed, there is no local variable yet.
2. I close the file.
3. I open the file the line has been readed and variables now exists.

So, after that the solution was simple, I've made a local variable via

```
.dir-locals.el
```

file, and my files are encrypted automatically.